# equivalents for products?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I do not understand how to use the equivalents to find the millimoles of the theoretical product. This is the part that I'm struggling with the most. My TA says that after I find the millimoles using the equivalents, then I can solve for grams and the mL of water.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to find out the limiting reactant in the reaction, in your case it's seems that cyclohexanone is limiting reactant. Theoretically, one equivalent of cyclohexanone (27mmol) react completely with 2 equivalent of benzaldehye (54mmol),but benzaldehye is used in excess (73mmol) to gave one equivalent of product (27mmol) and two equivalent of water (54mmol). 
When you multiply 27mmol of product with mol. weight (274.36g/mol) which is equal to =7408mg/1000= 7.4g

Similar you can do for water as well.. 
I hope this would be helpful, right now i don't have pencil with me, otherwise i will post a picture to this problem. 
anyway if you didn't understand let me know.. 
sincerely,